# How to get clicked component open and rest closed in react accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**Accordion component:**

```
const Accordion = (props: AccordionProps) => {
  const { label, levels, activeId, id } = props
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false)
  const onPress = useEvent(() => {
    setIsExpand(!isExpand)
  })

  return (
    <YStack width={'100%'} space={14}>
      <XStack
        width="100%"
        position="relative"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-end"
        onPress={onPress}
        cursor="pointer"
        space={10}
      >
        <Square
          animation={'lazy'}
          rotate={isExpand ? '0deg' : '-90deg'}
        >
          <ChevronDownCircle size={'$2'} />
        </Square>
        <Text>
          {label}
        </Text>
      </XStack>
      <YStack
        animation={'lazy'}
        width={'100%'}
        overflow="hidden"
        height={!isExpand ? 0 : '100%'}
      >
        <Text>
          {levels}
        </Text>
      </YStack>
    </YStack>
  )
}
```

**Render Accordion**

```
{ScoreLevels.map((level, index) => {
                return (
                  <AccordionOne
                    key={`level_${index}`}
                    label={`${level.title}`}
                    levels={level.suggestion}
                    activeId={1}
                    id={level.id}
                  />
                )
              })}
```

After rendering the Accordion it will show the selected label's info.

**Expecting:** When tap on selected label, other label's info should hide.
Only selected label should be open, others should be close.

Comment: Lift your expanded state up to the component that renders the accordion and then when mapping, pass a prop to the specific accordion that you want expanded. See [Sharing State Between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const Accordion = (props: AccordionProps) => {
  const { label, levels, activeId, id } = props
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false)

  const onPress = useEvent(() => {
    setIsExpand(!isExpand)
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isExpand && activeId !== id) {
      setIsExpand(false)
    }
  }, [isExpand, activeId, id])

  return (
    <YStack width={'100%'} space={14}>
      <XStack
        width="100%"
        position="relative"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-end"
        onPress={onPress}
        cursor="pointer"
        space={10}
      >
        <Square
          animation={'lazy'}
          rotate={isExpand ? '0deg' : '-90deg'}
        >
          <ChevronDownCircle size={'$2'} />
        </Square>
        <Text>
          {label}
        </Text>
      </XStack>
      <YStack
        animation={'lazy'}
        width={'100%'}
        overflow="hidden"
        height={!isExpand ? 0 : '100%'}
      >
        <Text>
          {levels}
        </Text>
      </YStack>
    </YStack>
  )
}
```